# Issue on Verification error , first mismatch at type 0x0000

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am beginner in arduino. Here I tried to burn/upload a code from arduino IDE. Code executes successfully but problem is on uploading time. It shows Verification error , first mismatch at type 0x0000. 0x62 !=0x0c. I am trying to burn it from windows pc. Here is my code

```
int trigPin = 11;    // Trigger
int echoPin = 12;    // Echo
long duration, cm, inches;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  //Define inputs and outputs
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);


pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

// Convert the time into a distance
cm = (duration/2) / 29.1;     // Divide by 29.1 or multiply by 0.0343
inches = (duration/2) / 74;   // Divide by 74 or multiply by 0.0135

Serial.print(inches);
Serial.print("in, ");
Serial.print(cm);
Serial.print("cm");
Serial.println();

delay(250);
}
```

> Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino
> Uno" Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is
> 32256 bytes. Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory,
> leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes. An
> error occurred while uploading the sketch avrdude: verification error,
> first mismatch at byte 0x0000 0x62 != 0x0c avrdude: verification
> error; content mismatch @Piglet thanks for advice . Here is error
> details

Comment: this is C++, C tag removed. you should at least know which language you're dealing with

Comment: add more information: what Arduino model? genuine or clone? which board did you select? how is it connected?  post the complete console output of uploading your sketch

Comment: Please copy the output of the upload from the message view in the IDE and add it to your question. (Use the link [edit] below your question.) You are describing an upload error, this is independent of the specific sketch.

Comment: Anyway, you might like to ask this question on [StackExchange/Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Arduino uno , board arduino uno , connected through comport_3

Comment: ide : sketch_jan_25a

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000

         0x62 != 0x0c

avrdude: verification error; content mismatch



@Piglet thanks for advice . Here is error details .

Comment: please add informaiton by editing your post. do not add information in commetns

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of posts online about that error. You should be able to find them as well.

The most suggested solution is to burn the bootloader as in this post:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=453997.0

The bootloader is a small program that is on the Arduino Unos microcontroller. It is necessary to get your application on the the microcontroller via the USB interface.
You would need a IPS programmer otherwise.

To burn the bootloader you need a dedicated AVR ISP programmer or a second Arduino. You can get them for little money online.